# Accessing the phonegap File API in normal functions of javascript

Tags: javascript, cordova

I am creating custom camera app in android using Phonegap plugin. I want to load the images in the index.html file by requesting the file system. For that i am using Phonegap file API,

```
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, onFSSuccess, fail);
```

Since it is Phonegap API, it cannot be used outside the other Javascript functions other than "deviceready" event function of Phonegap. It is saying "`LocalFileSytem is not defined`".

I want to access the file system from some other functions of Javascript also.. Can anyone have idea about this? Please do help........

Answer (score 0):

From JavaScript you need to use the native code to access the SD card, ultimately phone gap API also uses this as the local file system.